# how to have stripe charge for shipping and only have one country for payments

Tags: javascript, html, css, stripe-payments, shopping-cart

so im setting up my website and currently can't charge for shipping and using stripe. I want to be able to do this but it isn't working. do I need to do this in the site or on code. next on the payment part inergrated by stripe it allows billing and shipping to every country however I only want uk at the moment. how do I do this. I can send my files if that is easier but please can someone help

I have tried YouTube tutorials but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: do these "youtube tutorials" show you how to do the things you're asking about? What about stripe documentation?

Comment: What are you using to integrate Stripe payments? Need some more detail and code snippets. There are many integration paths with Stripe.

Comment: Is your website built with WordPress and [WooCommerce](https://woo.com/document/setting-up-shipping-zones/)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.